# discord.js Get array out of fs.readdir

Tags: discord.js

I can read `emotes` in `fs.readdir` but I can't read them out of `fs.readdir` function. Is there any way to read them anywhere else?

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
    const fs = require("fs");   
    var emotes = [];

    fs.readdir("./images/gif", (err, files) => {
        if(err) console.log(err);
        let giffile = files;
        if(giffile.length <= 0) {
            return console.log("Couldn't find any gif files");
        }

        giffile.forEach((f, i) => {
            emotes.push(f.split(".")[0]);
        });
        console.log(emotes);
    });
    console.log(emotes);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that you can't read `emotes` outside of the callback function, but that you're missing the point of callbacks.

This:

```js
    fs.readdir("./images/gif", (err, files) => {
        ...
    });
```

is written like this for a very specific reason: you're calling a function `fs.readdir(path,callback)`, giving a function `(err, files) => { ... }` for the callback. Why doesn't `fs.readdir()` just return the results like any normal function instead of making you give it *another* function? It's because it's **asynchronous** - the function you give is actually *scheduled* to run some indeterminate time in the future when your OS is done reading from the disk - you have no idea when that might be, but you can tell it what to do whenever that time comes.

Your outer `run` function does not *wait* for this indeterminate time, if it did, your bot would freeze up until it's done reading, which is bad news. Instead, it schedules that callback to be called some time later and then carries right on to the next line - `console.log(emotes);`. Remember that the callback has not run yet, so `emotes` naturally has not been given any values.

If you need to write asynchronous code like synchronous code, the key is Promises and async/await. I see you've already marked the `run` function async, so you can easily wrap the `readdir` call in a Promise like this:

```js
    module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
        const fs = require("fs");   
        var emotes = [];

        await new Promise((resolve,reject) => { fs.readdir("./images/gif", (err, files) => {
            if(err) reject(err);
            let giffile = files;
            if(giffile.length <= 0) {
                return console.log("Couldn't find any gif files");
            }

            giffile.forEach((f, i) => {
                emotes.push(f.split(".")[0]);
            });
            resolve();
        });
        console.log(emotes); //works!
    }
```

Or, you can skip the whole callback using the [`fs.Promises` API](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api) on node v10 or later:

```js
    module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
        const fs = require("fs").promises;   
        var emotes = [];

        var files = await fs.readdir("./images/gif");

        let giffile = files;
        if(giffile.length <= 0) {
            return console.log("Couldn't find any gif files");
        }

        giffile.forEach((f, i) => {
            emotes.push(f.split(".")[0]);
        });

        console.log(emotes); //works!
    }
```

Or much shorter and more efficient:

```js
    const fs = require("fs").promises; 

    module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
        var emotes = (await fs.readdir("./images/gif")).map(f => f.split(".")[0]);
        if(emotes.length <= 0) {
            return console.log("Couldn't find any gif files");
        }

        console.log(emotes); //works!
    }
```